# Definition 10.46(Area elements in $\Bbb R^{3}$) Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\Phi$ be a $2$-surface in $\Bbb R^{3}$ , of class $C^{1}$, with parameter domain $ D \subset \Bbb R^{2}$. Associate each point $(u,v) \in D$ with a vector $$N(u,v)= \frac{\partial (y,z)}{\partial (u,v)}e_{1}+\frac{\partial (z,x)}{\partial (u,v)}e_{2}+\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}e_{3} \tag1$$
>   The Jacobians in $(1)$ correspond to the equation $$(x,y,z)=\Phi (u,v) \tag2$$
>   If $f$ is a continuous function on $\Phi (D)$, the area integral of $f$ over $\Phi$ is defined to be 
>   $$\int_{\Phi} fdA=\int_{D} f(\Phi (u,v))|N(u,v)|du dv$$

Can someone give an example about $N(u,v)$? If it's a vector, what does "Jacobians in $(1)$" mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are determinants of the derivatives of the three maps from $\mathhb{R}^2$ to itself coming from projecting onto the coordinate hyperplanes. Although baby Rudin is a classic, you would do well to read about surfaces somewhere else.

Comment: See definition $9.38$. They define the symbol $\frac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial(u,v)}$ to be the determinant of $h'$, where $(y,z)=(y(u,v),z(u,v))=h(u,v)$, for some function $h$. In this case you would get $\frac{\partial (y,z)}{\partial(u,v)}=\det\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Can you explain what does $|N(u,v)|$ mean?

Comment: The norm of a vector:$|ae_1+be_2+ce_3|=\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2}$. It is defined in $1.36$.

Comment: The full Pythagorean theorem says the area of a parallelogram  is the square root of the sum of the squares of the areas of each of its projections into the coordinate planes. The formula is an infinitesimal version of that.